# Installing windowbuilder in adt juno 4.2.1

Tags: adt, eclipse-juno, windowbuilder

I am both an android developer and a swing developer. I usually use a adt-version of eclipse that was downloaded from google with android development tools, this version seems to be juno 4.2.1.

I am now looking to install windowbuilder in that same eclipse for my swing development, so that I don't have to change eclipse instances all the time when switching between android and swing work.

I have installed windowbuilder core 1.5.2 from help-install new software with no install errors.

The problem is that the windowbuilder doesn't show up. No windowbuilder options under preferences, and no new editors available.

The following link, http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ffaq.html under the title "What should I do if WindowBuilder Pro does not appear after installation?" states the following:

"WindowBuilder Pro requires the complete Eclipse SDK to be present, and will not load into an Eclipse subset (like EasyEclipse or the MyEclipse All-in-one edition). The most important piece missing from some Eclipse distributions is the Eclipse PDE (Plug-in Development Environment). You can correct this problem by launching Eclipse and selecting Help > Software Updates"

It seems that the adt bundle from google is not a complete eclipse sdk either then, but I have now installed the plug-in development environment, but no changes to the windowbuilder (even tried to uninstall and install windowbuilder after the plugin-environment install, but no luck)

What else do I have to do to make the adt accept the windowbuilder?

I would not like to do a complete re-install of eclipse/adt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem for my students using an Eclipse. I discovered that the problem was installing the tool at one time. When I installed the components, one at a time, it worked.

1. Visit http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php
2. Click the link for the integration version of 4.2 (Juno)
3. Copy the URL
4. In Eclipse go to Help | Install new software
5. Paste the site URL you copied, and
6. Select the Window Builder Engine
7. Click the buttons to finish, you will have to restart Eclipse
8. Revisit Help | install new software
9. Select the URL you added
10. Check on Swing designer
11. Click the buttons to finish, you will have to restart Eclipse. Say yes to warnings

If you also want SWT, repeat the last 4 steps but select SWT.

Then after relaunching Ecplise, File | New | Other | WindowBuilder should launch the wizard.

Comment: Thanx. I have changed pc/eclipse build since I wrote my question, so cannot verify, but I assume it would help, so marking it as answer.

Comment: There is no "link for the integration version of 4.2 (Juno)" on the referred page. May be contents changed after you referred it here. Where to go now?